# second character from the left apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Web App in Apps Script where I have a string of 18 characters but I only want to grab the second character from the left.  I have the 18 character string in a cell in my spreadsheet but set the value of a Textbox in the Web App to be the second character in that 18 character string.

```
function doGet(e) {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AhvH2AsQokNfdDFQUVUxM3hqLVhSdnVmUXdrRUlmYXc');
var s = doc.getSheetByName('X1_Pricing_Packaging');
var lstRow = s.getLastRow();
var app = UiApp.createApplication()
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(80, 50).setId('grid');
var range = s.getDataRange();
var rows = range.getNumRows();

var cPkg1ABx = app.createTextBox().setName('cPkg1ABx').setId('cPkg1ABx');
grid.setWidget(7, 7, cPkg1ABx);

var packageAData = (s.getRange(lstRow, 19, 1, 1).getValue());

app.getElementById('cPkg1ABx').setValue(packageAData.substring(2,1).getValue()).setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center")

  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`var secondCharFromTheLeft = packageAData[1];`

He asked how to get the second char, that gives the second element in the array, not much more you can say about it.

Comment: -1, Please don't just dump code, include an explanation.

Comment: quality matters on SO, poor posts get down voted, good posts get upvoted. SO strives to be a repository of knowledge, your answer may provide the solution, but even with your edit, it doesn't provide substance

Comment: Thanks for helping out a Newbie!